Bad Request error in passport-google-oauth
I am trying to implement a Google-based authentication using passport.js.
But I am getting Bad Request error
Steps for error

Go to localhost:3000/auth/google
selected the Google email

Then this error occurs

This is my main.js file
import express from "express"
import dotenv from "dotenv"
dotenv.config()
import { authRouter } from "./routes/auth"

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT

app.use('/auth', authRouter)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})

This is my authRoute
import { Router, Request, Response } from 'express'
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from 'passport-google-oauth20';

import passport from "passport"
const router = Router()

if (!process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID || !process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET) {
    throw new Error('Missing Google OAuth credentials in environment variables');
}

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback",
},
    (accessToken: any, refreshToken: any, profile: any, done: any) => {
        console.log(`accessToken -> ${accessToken}, refreshToken -> ${refreshToken}, profile -> ${profile} `)
        return done(null, profile)
    })
)

router.use('/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', { session: false, scope: ['profile', 'email'] })
)

router.get('/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        console.log("inside callback")
        res.redirect('/')
    }
)

export { router as authRouter }

Could anyone help me in identifying the problem?

Can you share your server code?
